# Appending data value from parent to child element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product grid page.  Each product is wrapped in a container div (class="container"). That div has a part number in a data-part-id element.  Nested within the container div is a span (class="name" that contains the part name.  I want to use jquery to fetch the parent part number and insert it after each part name contained within the span. Below is my code:

```
require(['jquery','domReady'],function($,domReady) {
    domReady(function(){
        $('container').each(function(index,v) {
            var $v = $(v);
            $v.find('span.name').append($v.data('data-part-id'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Supply the HTML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$v.data('data-part-id')` use `$v.data('part-id')` or `$v.attr('data-part-id')`
and you also missing a dot in container selector. Since container is a class, it should be `$('.container')` instead of `$('container')`
So your code should be

```
domReady(function(){
        $('.container').each(function(index,v) {
            var $v = $(v);
            $v.find('span.name').append($v.data('part-id'));
        });
    });
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w08Lyhaq/)

Comment: If it solves your issue please consider up-voting and marking as an answer

Comment: Thanks again.  My votes don't count because I'm still new.  Added as answer.